# What is the best way to handle special characters for Google searches?

Tags: google, domains, language

For example, originally my name is Denny Müller but I have used Denny Mueller for many years. This is common practice in Germany and it has the same meaning but with a different way of writing it.

I like to write it my name with *ue* but in Germany it is usually *ü*. Also my domain is with *ue* and it's easy to find at Google if I look for *denny mueller*. But anyone in Germany looking for my name would write it with *ü* and it is impossible to find in Google.

Is there a preferred way to handle this double layout?

Edit: `google.de` works fine but not on `google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Google usually maps *ü* and *ue* and searching for Danny Müller just a second ago, I see your website on 5th place just behind some Facebook profiles and some image search results:

[Google Search](https://www.google.de/search?q=denny%20m%C3%BCller&aq=f&oq=denny%20m%C3%BCller&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

That's true for `google.de` but I just tested `google.com` in English and it seems like Google is mapping *ü*=>*u* and thus not showing your website.

To solve this you might need more content and to include a different writing of your lastname e.g. Müller or Muller somewhere in the page. Maybe just in the meta description. Meta keywords won't help on Google, so Müller as you put there will not work.

I just saw that you put `lang="en"` may be changing this to `de` and telling Google this will help. I would also set the following meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="de">
<meta http-equiv="language" content="de">
<meta name="language" content="de">
```

Comment: thats right on the google.de, but many people also use google.com and there i dont appear.

Comment: result vary, and Google returns results based on your isp ip location..... try using a us vpn or uk and you see what I mean. \

Answer (score 0):

The results from `.de` and `.com` Google are expected to vary. If you want to rank well on the `.com` then your website needs tweaking.

- Do not write your content in German
- Do not write titles, alts, tags, metas in German
- Ideally don't use a .de domain, but not required.

The `.com` of Google is associated with English speaking sites. 'WEBENTWICKLER UND DESIGNER' for example will not help you in getting remarkable Google rankings on the `.com`.

Additionally the sites beating your rankings are offering more content than you, or they have more authority and age. While the competitors for the phrase "Denny Mueller" have better rankings the pages are not very strong. Adding more than just social links to your website, i.e. write some content about yourself on the site, will increase your rankings as well as off page SEO such as backlinks with the anchors "your name".